# Execute exe-file over ssh from Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration, command-prompt

I'm having a issue with CI where after i deployed a build i can't get the new version to start. In Jenkins the console output just keeps spinning when it hit the part of the batch file to start the exe-file and then times out.

I have tried both to run it inside the batch file and from the SSH command line but i can't get it to start on our Windows server.

Any suggestions?